# RxJS dynamic source of observables

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

I want to create an Observable of many observables (merge them). This could be achieved with `merge(...arrayOfObservables)`. The problem is that some time this array will be changed and the observable should subscribe to the new observables, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can push new Observables to an array and then emit the array and subscribe to them with `switchMap`.

```
import { of, merge, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs'; 
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const s = new BehaviorSubject([of(1), of(2), of(3)]);

s.pipe(
  switchMap(array => merge(...array)),
).subscribe(x => console.log(x));

s.next([...s.getValue(), of(4)]);
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-vmcqs9

Comment: This works like a charm! The only thing I am not sure if when I add/remove observable, the Subject won't miss any data from the rest of the observables?

Comment: `switchMap` will unsubscribe so you can use `concatMap` or `mergeMap` instead.

Comment: Something that I forgot to mention is that the observables are hot. Just tested it out with `switchMap` and works well. Seems no data was skipped. But again is there any chance when data will be missed in this case?