# RxJS: How to merge observables dynamically

Tags: rxjs

I want to combine 2 or more observables dynamically into one combined observable.

I understood how to combine two observables that already exist with `merge`, but how can I solve "merging" when the additional observable needs to be added dynamically (e.g. after a timeout)?

Also the existing subscriptions on `combinedStream$` should not be lost when merging another observable "on the fly".

Here is what I have so far:

```
const action1$ = interval(1000).pipe(map(data => 'Action1 value:' + data));
const action2$ = interval(1000).pipe(map(data => 'Action2 value:' + data));

const combinedStream$ = merge(action1$, action2$);
combinedStream$.subscribe(data => console.log('Combined Stream Output:', data));

// Add another observable after some time...
setTimeout(() => {
  const action3$ = interval(1000).pipe(map(data => 'Action3 value:' + data));
  // How add this action3$ to the combined stream ?
}, 1000);
```

Here is my stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-s2cyzj

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59916768/rxjs-dynamic-source-of-observables

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When dealing with that use case, the easiest thing to do is to have an observable... of observable and then use a higher order function like [concatAll](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-concatAll), [switch](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-switch), [mergeAll](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeAll)...

```
const action1$: Observable<string> = interval(2000).pipe(
  map(data => "Action1 value:" + data)
);
const action2$: Observable<string> = interval(2000).pipe(
  map(data => "Action2 value:" + data)
);
const action3$: Observable<string> = interval(2000).pipe(
  map(data => "Action3 value:" + data)
);

const mainStream$$: Subject<Observable<string>> = new Subject();

const combinedStream$ = mainStream$$.pipe(mergeAll());

combinedStream$.subscribe(data => console.log("Combined Stream Output:", data));

mainStream$$.next(action1$);
mainStream$$.next(action2$);
// Add another stream after some time...
setTimeout(() => {
  mainStream$$.next(action3$);
}, 1000);
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-stwvtc?file=index.ts

Comment: How to remove Observable dynamically?

Comment: The same way you'd with a classic observable? takeUntil, takeWhile, first, take, ... use any operator that'd close one stream and apply that to the stream you want to close?

Comment: @maxime1992 How would I catch an error along the main stream? `pipe(mergeAll(), catchError(...))` does not seem to work.

Comment: @maxime1992 It's not working in the sense that on error the queue stops

Comment: Use `catchError` on individual streams.

Comment: @maxime1992 So really no way to do this on subject level?