# Extensible chain of promises

Tags: typescript, async-await, promise, rxjs

I have multiple functions reading from/writing to the same file. The functions are called after certain HTTP requests. Thus, to avoid conflicts when accessing the same file simultaneously, I build some kind of promise chain:

```ts
class PromiseChain {
  private current: Promise<any> = Promise.resolve();

  public push<T, TResult1 = T, TResult2 = never>(
    onfulfilled?:
      | ((value: T) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>)
      | undefined
      | null,
    onrejected?:
      | ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<TResult2>)
      | undefined
      | null
  ): Promise<TResult1 | TResult2> {
    return (this.current = this.current.then(onfulfilled).catch(onrejected));
  }
}
```

which can be used like so:

```ts
const chain = new PromiseChain();
const defer = (message: string, timeout: number) => () =>
  new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(message), timeout)).then(
    console.log
  );

chain.push(defer('1st', 1000), (error) => console.log(error.message));
chain.push(defer('2nd', 500));
```

Thus, the promises are being executed in the same order they have been pushed to the chain (`1st` then `2nd`). Errors along the chain can be caught, so the chain will not break.

Is there any built-in or an easier way to achieve this? I was thinking along the lines of rxjs Subjects or the like.

Comment: "*errors along the chain can be caught*" - but you're not actually doing it!

Comment: "*Is there any built-in or an easier way to achieve this?*" - the example you've given can be trivially simplified not use a class instance, just write `Promise.resolve().then(defer('1st', 1000)).then(defer('2nd', 500));`. So what do you actually need?

Comment: @Bergi The calls to `push` come from different functions at different times (as I've already explained), so it's not only one line.

Comment: @Bergi I've added an error handler to my example code, but that should not make a huge difference.

Comment: The example caller in the OP says: `const chain = new PromiseChain();`. That will produce a new chain. Unless another caller hangs the next promise on the very same `chain`, the promises will resolve independently.  Make the promise chain class a singleton, or use a global version of `current`, which is about the same thing

Comment: @danh Well that's what I'm doing. Even in my simplified example both calls of `push` are on the same `chain`. I don't get the point

Comment: ok so you `push` two `defer` on the `chain` and they will run in sequence.. can you explain what happens next?  guessing something like `chain.current.then(result => ...)`? what is the type of `result`?

Comment: it looks like you're reinventing `.then`

Comment: @DonFuchs, but it seems like you're getting expected results.  Begin a longer running promise, `then` a quicker running promise. The quicker one will start *after* the longer one resolves.

Comment: "*The calls to `push` come from different functions at different times*" - then what you did is fine. No, there is no builtin that makes it easier - but I don't see how the `push` implementation could get any simpler

Comment: @Bergi Yes, this already pretty simple, and it meets all my requirements. I was just wondering if maybe my overall approach may be wrong. For such a basic problem it just does not feel perfectly right, I've never seen sth like this. Also, I thought rxjs might have something built-in in store.

Comment: @DonFuchs With rxjs you'd probably use a stream of reads and writes per file, emitted from across the application(?), and then `concatAll` or `concatMap` them

Comment: @Bergi That's what I was thinking of... could you maybe elaborate on that, I'm not very familiar with streams.

Comment: @DonFuchs If you're not already familiar with rxjs and not already using it, then your `PromiseChain` will definitely be simpler, faster, and easier to understand

Comment: @Bergi rxjs is fine, only file streams I don't know very well. If I knew how to replace `readFile`/`writeFile` with file stream operations I would manage the rxjs bit myself. If I had for example a global stream, keeping the file open all the time and piping in data from different functions one by one, maybe that would be a better approach?!

Comment: @DonFuchs I meant that every action you'd do on a file would be an item ("event"?) in the stream. You could then of course optimise your file operations globally in various ways with stream operators. Whether that's a "better" or even "suitable" approach depends on what exactly you need, which you probably should ask as a new question.

Comment: @Bergi Ok, thanks. I posted another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76841438/fs-best-way-of-mutual-asynchronous-read-write-to-single-file

Answer (score -1):

What you're looking for is the [`concat`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/concat) operator:

```
import { of, delay, concat } from 'rxjs';

const mockValues = [
  of(`1st`).pipe(delay(1000)),
  of(`2nd`).pipe(delay(1000)),
  of(`3rd`).pipe(delay(1000)),
];

concat(...mockValues).subscribe(console.log);
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-4dg1xr?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts)

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. Once subscribed it's not possible to add any observable.

Comment: I see. I misunderstood. What you then want is this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59922635/2398593 and use concatAll

Comment: Great, exactly what I was looking for!! I knew they would be something like that